# How many times does syndrome extraction need to be repeated?

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance

As part of implementing a QEC code, we need to do some syndrome measurement. In order for this syndrome measurement, we need to make sure that any $k \leq t$ errors (with a distance $2t + 1$ code) propagate to at most $k$ errors on the data. Shor's method (outlined [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605011)) ensures that errors on the ancilla qubits do not propagate to correlated errors on the data.

However, the received syndrome may still be incorrect due to an error on an ancilla, which could lead us to apply an incorrect correction. In the $t = 1$ case, I believe this does not impact fault tolerance, since any correction applied will be weight one, and assuming there is an ancilla error and $k \leq t$ implies there is no data error to start with, leaving at most one error on the data.

For the $t = 2$ case though I find myself confused on the procedure. Shor suggests in his 1997 paper (linked above) repeating until you receive the same syndrome measurement $O(\log t)$ times in a row. This gives a probabalistic guarantee that the syndrome received is correct, but is not strictly fault tolerant. I can also convince myself that repeating $3$ times for the $t = 2$ case is strictly fault tolerant (if taking majority vote of syndromes) but I do not know what the general recipe is for arbitrary $t$.

Any references on Shor's method for syndrome extraction and how many times it must be repeated as a function of $t$ would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You can take a look at this lecture from Gottesman: https://pirsa.org/18020009 after the first hour he talks about the Shor measurement and how many times you should repeat it.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent lecture suggestion, and the time stamp. Very helpful.